# Different Results With Inner Select Statement

Tags: sqlite

This query gives me 7 results:

```
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT film.id FROM film 
INNER JOIN film_release ON film_release.fk_film = film.id 
INNER JOIN film_release_files ON film_release.id = film_release_files.fk_film_release 
INNER JOIN file ON file.id = film_release_files.fk_file 
ORDER BY download_date DESC LIMIT 7;
id        
----------
4525      
4530      
4529      
4528      
4527      
4524      
4526
```

If I select of these 7 IDs by putting them in an IN clause, I get just 6 results:

```
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT film.id FROM film 
INNER JOIN film_details ON film.id = film_details.fk_film WHERE film.id in (
   SELECT DISTINCT film.id FROM film 
   INNER JOIN film_release ON film_release.fk_film = film.id 
   INNER JOIN film_release_files ON film_release.id = film_release_files.fk_film_release 
   INNER JOIN file ON file.id = film_release_files.fk_file 
   ORDER BY download_date DESC LIMIT 7
) 
ORDER BY film.title, film.year;
id        
----------
4525      
4524      
4527      
4528      
4529      
4530
```

But if I copy and paste the results from the inner query as a list, rather than the select statement, I get all 7 back:

```
sqlite> SELECT DISTINCT film.id FROM film INNER JOIN film_details ON film.id = film_details.fk_film WHERE film.id in (
   4525, 4530, 4529, 4528, 4527, 4524, 4526
) ORDER BY film.title, film.year;
id        
----------
4525      
4524      
4526      
4527      
4528      
4529      
4530
```

What's up with this? Is there a workaround to fix this? Am I misunderstanding something here, or is it a bug?

I'm seeing this in 3.8.7.1 2014-10-29 13:59:56 3b7b72c4685aa5cf5e675c2c47ebec10d9704221.
But I do not see it with the same database in 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30 27392118af4c38c5203a04b8013e1afdb1cebd0d

Comment: Since this is version specific you should check the [release notes of the version between 3.8.2 and 3.8.7](https://www.sqlite.org/chronology.html) for a behaviour change and file a bug with sqlite, if you do not find an explanation. Do you also see the behaviour with the **current version Version 3.26.0 (2018-12-01)**? If not use this one, it was probably a bug.

Comment: I think maybe it's this: sqlite.org/releaselog/3_8_4_3.html but it's pretty ambiguous. I guess it matches what I'm seeing, but they just say it "might" cause "incorrect query results". Anyway, thanks for that link with the version updates.
But also, it works in the older version but not the more up-to-date one, even if it's not the current Version.

Comment: [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_regression) is always a problem in complex software. You should check if the problem still occurs in the most recent version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is is probably this issue https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/db87229497 which was introduced in version 3.8.6

> This bug can be hit when an IN operator has a subquery on its
>   right-hand side and the subquery contains both a DISTINCT keyword and
>   a LIMIT clause.

it is fixed in version 3.8.7.2.

A workaround for version 3.8.7.1 would be not to use `DISTINCT` and `LIMIT` combined in `IN` statements.

Nevertheless 3.8.7.2 is from 2014 and you should really switch to the most recent version if possible.

Found searching on this site https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html